# Graph Copy file operation requires OneDrive file to be shared

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

When I make a copy item request to the Graph API (as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-copy), I get an "Access Denied" error on the request unless I create a shareable link on the file.  My app registration already requests Files.ReadWrite.All.  Shouldn't that scope grant access to copy operations for all files without requiring that those files be shared?  The documentation makes no note of this sharing requirement.

Here's what my request and response was:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/01U5HU23DLMANTOZOCBRCKZAXZ22PYNRGR/copy HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0...SNIP!!!!...
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Content-Length: 211
Expect: 100-continue

{"name" : "Copy-01U5HU23DLMANTOZOCBRCKZAXZ22PYNRGR.pptx", "parentReference" :  { "driveId": "b!bLRKCe6UoEmhaguLIR83GAjYCavRyBRLs_igqUdAHTpAwbmf4u0ESLPbDrjCEr2w",  "id": "01U5HU23F6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ" } } }

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: 7c26c462-805f-4c26-90e3-8ee22ba719c6
client-request-id: 7c26c462-805f-4c26-90e3-8ee22ba719c6
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Canada East","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_10"}}
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Fri, 18 Dec 2020 02:45:37 GMT
Content-Length: 279

{
  "error": {
    "code": "accessDenied",
    "message": "Access denied",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-12-18T02:45:37",
      "request-id": "7c26c462-805f-4c26-90e3-8ee22ba719c6",
      "client-request-id": "7c26c462-805f-4c26-90e3-8ee22ba719c6"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the exact call that you are using and the whole error response with requestid and timestamp.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity I updated my question with the request and response

Comment: Looks like you have Files.Read.All but not Files.ReadWrite.All so according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-copy?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) you need to have Files.ReadWrite.All or Files.ReadWrite as you said.

Comment: Please let me know if it helped you.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity I did note that my code to call ConfidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode was not setting the correct scopes, but I had corrected it, revoked and re-established permissions to my app registration and still received that error.

Comment: Please try reproducing this issue in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) or POSTMAN. I have tested it in Graph Explorer and it was working fine with just Files.ReadWrite

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity It was working for me in the Graph Explorer, and now it IS working for me in my app. It must have been some weird caching issue since my initial app authorization with the wrong scopes. Thanks for your help and the important clue!!

Comment: Glad that it resolves your issue. Moving this to Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have Files.Read.All but not Files.ReadWrite.All so according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-copy?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) you need to have Files.ReadWrite.All or Files.ReadWrite as you said.

Also test with Graph Explorer or POSTMAN so that you can debug where the issue is.